# Sequelize: how to prevent execution of following validators if the current one is failed

Tags: validation, sequelize.js

I have a field in a model with some few validators:

```
...
someField: {
  ...
  validate: {
      someValidator1: true,
      someValidator2: true,
  }
}, 
...
```

Both validators in *Sequelize* are executed independently.

How to **not execute** the second one if the first one is failed?

Answer (score 1):

Script execution stops as soon as you throw an error.

At http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-definition/, the authors of Sequelize.js give this example:

```
var ValidateMe = sequelize.define('foo', {
  foo: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    validate: {
      // custom validations are also possible:
      isEven: function(value) {
        if(parseInt(value) % 2 != 0) {
          // This error will stop code execution and give you the chance to catch and handle the error
          throw new Error('Only even values are allowed!')
        // we also are in the model's context here, so this.otherField
        // would get the value of otherField if it existed
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```